# Save a boolean as null

Tags: ruby-on-rails

`dp1` has three possible states `true`, `false`, and `null`. I would like to save `dp1` as `null`. This is correctly done according to the logs, but it is saved as `true` while there is no default value in my db.

```
Started PATCH "/equipments/2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-08-01 11:49:23 +0200
Processing by EquipmentsController#update as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "equipment"=>{"title"=>"TV ", "dp1"=>"nil"}, "commit"=>"Save", "id"=>"2"}
  Equipment Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "equipment".* FROM "equipment" WHERE "equipment"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/equipments_controller.rb:124
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ /Users/Mesnet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/orm_adapter-0.5.0/lib/orm_adapter/adapters/active_record.rb:17
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/equipments_controller.rb:81
  Equipment Update (0.4ms)  UPDATE "equipment" SET "dp1" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "equipment"."id" = ?  [["dp1", 1], ["updated_at", "2018-08-01 09:49:23.413563"], ["id", 2]]
  ↳ app/controllers/equipments_controller.rb:81
   (0.7ms)  commit transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/equipments_controller.rb:81
  Rendering equipments/js/create.js.erb
  Rendered equipments/js/create.js.erb (0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 31ms (Views: 26.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.5ms)
```

How can I force my value to be saved as `null` if the form is `null`?

Comment: Hi @JagdeepSingh, thanks for your answer. I've tried to save the value as nil, null and none as you suggest, but is not working

Comment: Can you please share your controller and model code?

Comment: Yep, the false and the true is working

Comment: @krupasuthar, thanks for your answer. My controller is parametred as default

Comment: "dp1"=>"nil", it should be `nil` instead of string 'nil'

Comment: @stigGaret there must be some problem in your code as you can see the parameters contain title but title not being updated in the query

Comment: No, that's because the title was already "TV" before the update

Comment: Where is the request coming from? Ideally, you should not be receiving params `"dp1"=>"nil"`

Answer (score 0):

Only empty strings or `nil` value are coerced to `nil`. Please check the [boolean type documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Type/Boolean.html) for active record.

You will have to check for 'nil' string and convert it to empty string or nil value at controller level. Something like this:

```
def update
  .....
  data = params.require(: equipment).permit(:title, :dp1).to_h
  data[:dp1] = '' if data[:dp1] == 'nil'
  .....      
end
```